# What is the correct approach in React to loop through an array to build html-select list of items in a function and call it in render()?

Tags: reactjs, html-select

My first thought is to do it the conventional way, i.e. gather all data as strings in a function and return it as `dangerouslySetHtml`. I could later call the function as `{this.renderList()}` in `render()`. How do I  do it the "React Way", i.e. build `JSX` elements in a method and implement it in render()? Following is a random example of how I'd approach this situation.

```
constructor(props)
{
  super(props);
  this.state = {
     users: [{..}, {..}, {..}],
     info: [{..}, {..}]
  };
}

renderSelectDropdown()
{
    data = '<select>'

    this.state.users.forEach(user =>
    {   
        data +=  '<optgroup label={user.title}>';
        for (let item in this.state.info)
        {
            this.state.info[user.name][item].forEach(s => {
                data += '<option>'+ s +'</option>';
            })
        }
        data += '</optgroup>'
    });

    data += '</select>';

    return {__html: data};
}

render()
{
    return (

        <div>
            <input type="text" name="name">
            <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML = this.renderSelectDropdown()></div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
renderSelectDropdown() {
    let list = [];

    this.state.users.forEach((user, idx) =>
    {   
        let opt = this.state.info.map((item) => {
            this.state.info[user.name][item].map((s, key) => {
                <option key={key}>{s}</option>;
            })
        });

        list.push(<optgroup key={idx} label={user.title}>{opt}</optgroup>);

    });

    return list;
}

render() {
    let list = renderSelectDropdown();

    return (
        <div>
           <input type="text" name="name">
           <select>
              {list}
           </select>
        </div>
    )
 }
```

Comment: That's perfect!

Comment: Actually, there was one mistake. Forgot to set the value of each option. This should be: `<option key={key} value={s}>{s}</option>;`

Comment: Thanks a lot, Win!

Answer (score 0):

The react way is this simple

```
<div>
{this.state.users.map(user => {
  return <p> {user.prop} </p>
})}
</div>
```